# adding scoring feature on android app

Tags: android

Hi I have a spelling game application and it has 10 stages on it. There is a category assigned on each stages for example Stage 1 Animal, Stage 2 Things etc. and there are few questions per stages as well. Now I want to add scoring feature on it that will increment for every correct answer and deduct for every wrong answer. When the user finished all 10 stages there will be a high score that will appear and the user can input their names on it and save it to the database. Any idea how can I do that? I'm a beginner in android and JAVA. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement that, I will suggest you to use a local database. You will have to create a table  highscores for the moment with

- id
- name
- score

A good practice is maybe to create a table user and a table score (and connect them together), so your user will have more than one attribute (which is name if a single table is used).

For the database, Android uses SQLite: see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Then, in your app, you will have to catch when a step (level) is finished. When finished, you can get an instace of your database and of the desired table, and insert data inside.

When all the levels are finished, you can display the highscore and ask the user for his name and more if needed.

Learning how to manage a database in Android (and all the other languages) is very important. It is not easy if you are a beginner, but there are some good tutorials like:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html
- http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Use sharedprefrences here. take an int type variable increament it with +10 and deduct -10 using the simple if else. In the end use a custom dialog and which should ask user to enter name if he/she is a high scorer. High score can also be stored in the sharedprefrences or you also can store it in database.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a SQLite database to store the progress and current score for each user/playthrough, and a separate table to store the actual highscore.

SQLite in Android is actually pretty easy. It's best to start by reading [Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Comment: thanks for the reference sir but how can I program the scoring?

Comment: That strongly depends on how complicated your scoring scheme is and how your stages are set up. Is each stage a different Activity? If you just count the number of correct answers and deduct the number of wrong answers from that, you can just store an int in the database and update it after the answer is determined to be correct or incorrect by your program.

Comment: Then you can either work directly with the value from the database, or pass the current score as an extra in the intent that starts the next stage, or store the current score in a static variable in one of your classes. Except for the first method, however, you will lose any progress the player made if the app crashes or is otherwise terminated.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a singleton class that you call from your different classes and add points

```
import android.util.SparseArray;

public class Score{

public int score;
private static Scoreinstance;

private Score()
{

}

public static Score getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Score();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}

then call it with

```
Score.getInstance().score += "points to be added"
```

then save it to your database at the end

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html
this guy does some great and easy to understand tutorials